# Would Ryanair tolerate a 15.6" laptop case as a second hand luggage?

Tags: luggage, regulations, hand-luggage, ryanair

Ryanair recently changed the luggage rules [allowing a second small bag](http://www.ryanair.com/cz/terms-and-conditions/regulations-cabinbaggage/):

> One cabin bag weighing up to 10 kg with maximum dimensions of 55cm x 40cm x 20cm, **plus 1 small bag up to 35 x 20 x 20 cms may be carried per passenger**

I have a 15.6" laptop, which works out to 38cm width, or about 42 cm with a thin case. Would Ryanair tolerate the laptop exceeding the maximum width? The luggage sizers at the airport are open-ended, so theoretically one could fit the laptop case with the long side sticking on top.

Comment: Dont trust that only. My luggage was once measured with a ruler and that dimension was off by 2cm (I think even less) and had to pay extra. Having this said, they are currently a bit more layed back and it has become even nice to travel with them. Still I would advise not to abuse too much.

Comment: Easyjet and similar companies make money any way they can. Giving the choice between being really nice and letting you take a second bag slightly larger than allowed, or charging you, their choice is obvious. I'd put the laptop into the suitcase, and take a small bag with extra stuff that doesn't fit into the suitcase anymore.

Comment: Would they have to prove that the ruler they are using is fair? Metric fraud is a serious business (at least in my country), so there are lots of regulations.

Comment: When I used to travel with them years ago, they weighed each hand luggage (only at airports where they had the necessary setup) and they didn't let me take a 10.5 kg bag because the limit was 10.0 kg.  If they do measure, I would not expect them to tolerate even a few cm over the limit.

Comment: It'll certainly fit into the dimensions of your _other_ one cabin bag. But, as a rule, [low cost carriers will charge you for whatever they can get away with](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZAg0lUYHHFc).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Yes, any measuring equipment they used as a basis for charging you (e.g., the scales they use to weigh your luggag) would have to be properly calibrated. However, in the case of a simple ruler which has no moving parts so isn't going to change much over time, the regulations probably just say that the equipment has to be manufactured according to appropriate national standards and is in good physical condition.

Comment: Currently their [online FAQ](https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/help-centre/faq-overview/Baggage#0-1) says: "One small bag e.g. handbag, laptop bag etc. not exceeding 35cm x 20cm x 20cm", But even a 11" laptop would exceed that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've tried to pull it off on two Ryanair flights recently and the answer is: **yes, they allow it**. No one bothered to check the dimensions of my laptop case, but they did ask to measure the large bag on both occasions.

On the last flight the cabin was so full, some people were forced to surrender their hand luggage to be checked into the cargo hold, but my laptop bag was still safely ignored. I can't guarantee an overzealous employee somewhere won't bother checking the exact dimensions of the second bag, but it seems quite unlikely.

Comment: If they do make a fuss, you can temporarily place your laptop into your big cabin bag and take it out when you have borded the plane.

Answer (score 8):

From experience, if it doesn't fit WITHIN their measuring boxes, they won't allow it. This means that if it doesn't fit with/depth, or if it sticks out the top (as you're saying with the laptop), they'll deem it too large.

If your case is soft and can be folded up, I'd suggest considering having the case in your pocket, so that the laptop still fits in the measuring box, and then putting it back in the case once on the plane.  However, there are risks with this (damage to laptop, or them still not buying it - asking where the case is?).

It's a budget airline. They have strict rules, and charge less. Unfortunately sometimes this means the rules cause us difficulties, but it's the choice we make when flying with them.

Comment: Plus your luggage is likely to be checked again before boarding the plane.

Comment: I'm afraid this answer is not necessarily correct for Ryanair and the self-answer by @JonathanReez corresponds much more to my personal experience with Ryanair specifically. To make the other A more visible, -1